logic to use service once in a month in dart/flutter
I have two data 1)'usage count' and 2)'last used date' and requirement is to find if user has used service once in a month. If user has already used service once in a month return value should be false else it should be true. This is my code in dart. but its not working
bool checkValidity( int usageCount,DateTime lastUsed){
      int differenceInMonths =
          (lastUsed.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays / 30).floor();
  print('no of usage : $usageCount, past months : $differenceInMonths');
      return differenceInMonths >= usageCount ? false: true;
}

void main() {
   print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:28))));
   print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:29))));
   print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:30))));
   print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:31))));
   print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:60))));
   print(checkValidity(2,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:59))));
   print(checkValidity(2,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:60))));
   print(checkValidity(2,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:61))));
}


I'm not sure what the logic is behind the desired output. Why do you expect it to return true at the indicated spot? Also when I try your code it returns a much difference output. All falses and trues are the other way around

@Ivo I just made some edit, sorry for the confusion. So if the user uses a service every time usage count increases by one and lastUsed time is set to current time. Now checkValidity should return false if the service has already been used once in a month and true If service has not been used even once in a month.

I don't see how you would link the usage number to the last time used in order to see if they used it once a month. Shouldn't you just check if lastUsed is more than 30 days ago? if I for example use your service 10 months in a row every month once, then the next month I skip and the month after I use it again you have usage number 11 and past months 2. That's not very helpful to decide it. Maybe I'm misunderstanding

Did you maybe mean first time used? instead of last time used?

My desired output was totally wrong so deleted it but I got my answer and just posted it

bool checkValidity( int usageCount,DateTime lastUsed){
      int differenceInMonths =
          (lastUsed.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays / 30).floor();
  print('no of usage : $usageCount, past months : $differenceInMonths');
      return differenceInMonths >= usageCount ? true : false;
}

void main() {
print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:28))));
print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:29))));
print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:30))));
print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:31))));
print(checkValidity(1,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:60))));
print(checkValidity(2,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:59))));
print(checkValidity(2,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:60))));
print(checkValidity(2,DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:61))));
}
This should be the output
no of usage : 1, past months : 0
false
no of usage : 1, past months : 0
false
no of usage : 1, past months : 1
false
no of usage : 1, past months : 1
false
no of usage : 1, past months : 2
true
no of usage : 2, past months : 1
false
no of usage : 2, past months : 2
false
no of usage : 2, past months : 2
false

